How to enable "azure monitor" on All APIs level in azure api management by using terraform?
I am trying to enable button for "azure monitor" which comes inside Azure API Management service. We need to navigate to All APIs in APIM and then from there, select Settings tab and then enable Azure monitor tab through Terraform. Then need to configure few settings inside. But I am not getting any option to do the job. It is clearly mentioned in Terraform documentation that it is done for both "application insights" & "azure monitor" but I am unable to do it for azure monitor.
Any support or leads will be highly appreciated.
I tried to run the terraform script from the below link but sometimes, my "terraform plan" is success and sometimes failing. But my "terraform apply" is never success.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_diagnostic
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}
 
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
 
locals {
  api_names = ["api1-name","echo-api"]
}
 
data "azurerm_api_management" "api_name" {
  name                = "demo-test-1"
  resource_group_name = "az104"
}
 
data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics" {
  name                = "demo-test-23"
  resource_group_name = "az104"
}
 
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "api-insight" {
  name                = "api-appinsights-123"
  location            = data.azurerm_api_management.api_name.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management.api_name.resource_group_name
  application_type    = "web"
}
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_logger" "example" {
  name                  = "demo-test-1-logger"  # Provide a unique name for your logger
  api_management_name = "demo-test-1"
  resource_group_name = "az104"
 
 
  application_insights {
    instrumentation_key = azurerm_application_insights.api-insight.instrumentation_key
 
  }
}
 
data "azurerm_api_management_api" "apis" {
  for_each             = toset(local.api_names)
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_api_management.api_name.resource_group_name
  api_management_name  = data.azurerm_api_management.api_name.name
  name                 = each.key
  revision = "1"
}
 
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_diagnostic" "allapis" {
  for_each                 = data.azurerm_api_management_api.apis
 
  identifier               = "azuremonitor"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_api_management_api.apis[each.key].resource_group_name
  api_management_name      = data.azurerm_api_management_api.apis[each.key].api_management_name
  api_name                 = each.key
  api_management_logger_id = azurerm_api_management_logger.example.id
  sampling_percentage      = 100.0
  always_log_errors        = false
  log_client_ip            = true
  verbosity                = "information"
 
  frontend_request {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "X-Request-Id",
      "Origin",
      "Authorization",
      "User-Agent"
    ]
  }
 
  frontend_response {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "X-Request-Id",
      "Origin",
      "Authorization",
      "User-Agent"
    ]
  }
 
  backend_request {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "X-Request-Id",
      "Authorization",
      "User-Agent"
    ]
  }
 
  backend_response {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "X-Request-Id",
      "Authorization",
      "User-Agent"
    ]
  }
 
#   lifecycle {
#     ignore_changes = [operation_name_format]
#   }
}
 
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "existing" {
  name                    = "azuremonitor-12"
  target_resource_id      = data.azurerm_api_management.api_name.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id
 
  enabled_log {
    category = "GatewayLogs"
  }
 
  enabled_log {
    category = "WebSocketConnectionLogs"
  }
 
  enabled_log {
    category = "DeveloperPortalAuditLogs"
  }
 
  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
    enabled  = true
  }
}
 
output "apim_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_api_management.api_name.id
}
 
output "log_analytics_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id
}


please share the code you tried @ObaidurRahmanSyed


How to enable "azure monitor" on All APIs level in azure api management by using terraform

The statement mentioned "application insights" & "azure monitor" from the terraform registry is mentioning the diagnostic setting creation based on the target resource we can make the setting readily available to enable under APIs list in APIM --> Settings tab.
This option can't be provisioned using terraform or CLI as I tried to update the APIs using --set custom properties but there is no direct option as of now rather than manual intervention.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_api_management_diagnostic" "example" {
  identifier               = "applicationinsights"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name      = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  api_management_logger_id = azurerm_api_management_logger.example.id

  sampling_percentage       = 5.0
  always_log_errors         = true
  log_client_ip             = true
  verbosity                 = "verbose"
  http_correlation_protocol = "W3C"

  frontend_request {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "accept",
      "origin",
    ]
  }

  frontend_response {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "content-length",
      "origin",
    ]
  }

  backend_request {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "accept",
      "origin",
    ]
  }

  backend_response {
    body_bytes = 32
    headers_to_log = [
      "content-type",
      "content-length",
      "origin",
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "apim_monitoring" {
  name                       = "apim-monitoring"
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_api_management.example.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
  log_analytics_destination_type = "Dedicated"   
  enabled_log {
    category = "GatewayLogs"
  }
  enabled_log {
    category = "WebSocketConnectionLogs"
  }
  enabled_log {
    category = "DeveloperPortalAuditLogs"
  }
  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
    enabled  = true
  }
}

deployment:




Refer:
azurerm_api_management_diagnostic | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting.html#log_analytics_workspace_id
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/azurediagnostics#azure-diagnostics-mode-or-resource-specific-mode
